# Need to convert datetime to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

In my csv file, I have date column as dd/mm/yyyy. However, when I import it into Python 3, it automatically changes the entire column to yyyy/mm/dd and its data type is an object.

I have tried converting it back to dd/mm/yyyy with this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(df_sales_sum['Date'], "%Y/%m/%d").datetime.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

However, it returned me with this

> `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series`

Am i supposed to convert the `df_sales_sum['Date']` part to a string first? And from what I know, datetime automatically converts it to yyyy/mm/dd. Correct me if im wrong.

Any help on converting it from `yyyy/mm/dd` to `dd/mm/yyyy` will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I would make df_sales_sum['Date'] a string: str(df_sales_sum['Date']). See if that helps. However, I'm not sure what df_sales_sum['Date'] output is.

```
df_date = str(df_sales_sum['Date'])

convert_date = df_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Good luck.

Comment: Have you tried above code, does it work ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should help:

```
df['Column_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column_name'], format='%d%m%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

The error said that, you should convert **df_sales_sum['Date']** to python string first. Then strptime will accept that string to convert to a datetime object.